# Set Configuration when using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project?

Tags: msbuild, microsoft.build

I can build a project with the following

```cs
static bool Build()
{
    var projectCollection = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection;
    var project = projectCollection.LoadProject(websiteProject);

    var fileLogger = new FileLogger();
    fileLogger.Parameters = @"logfile=" + @"app_data\log.txt";
    projectCollection.RegisterLogger(fileLogger);


    bool result = project.Build();
    projectCollection.UnregisterAllLoggers();
    return result;
}
```

But I need to be able to set the build configuration to Release. I've had a look through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project%28v=vs.121%29.aspx), but either I'm missing it or there's not an easy way to set it.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer:

```cs
projectCollection.SetGlobalProperty("Configuration", "Release");
```